# DeployURL is deprecated, is there a planned alternative aside from baseHref?

Tags: angular, angular-elements

The plan to eliminate the deployUrl option makes sense to me when thinking of a regular application, as the baseHref doesn't alter code. But before it gets removed, I wanted to get clarification of an alternative when there's no index.html file to host the tag to support it.

My situation involves web components that are downloaded from a location that is different from the web page.

Example:
Website A, at a.com, makes a lot of requests to a.com/*.
Website A imports a web component JS file from b.com/web-components/*, and gets its assets from the same location.

In this situation, a web component made with Angular wouldn't be able to retrieve its assets from b.com/web-components/* without a.com pointing the baseHref to it, which would break a.com.